# Can't authorize into Http request

Tags: http, web, postman, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Sorry for my English)

I have an account on https://naurok.com.ua (login: kuz.code.official@gmail.com, password: 2455s1). I log in, then follow the link [/test/test-po-filosofii-541029/flashcard](https://naurok.com.ua/test/test-po-filosofii-541029/flashcard).

After I followed the link, it loads the cards through a request [/api/test/documents/541029/flashcard](https://naurok.com.ua/api/test/documents/541029/flashcard).

**I need to send it successfully:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I test request by Postman [api/test/documents/541029/flashcard](https://naurok.com.ua/api/test/documents/541029/flashcard). Request sends with captured Cookies, but it says I need to log in ("Необходимо авторизоваться").

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Why query work on website but doesn`t in Postman?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need add the most important thing which is to add the cookie PHPSESSID you can find it on your browser when inspecting the request on network tab
like this

[image]

click on "cookies" on postman

to have it like this

[image: cookies]

or click on "code" on postman

[image]

I noticed also you need referer header otherwise it won't work

[image]